# On menu li hover, submenu pops in instead of fading in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I'm a minor issue with my navigation bar. When I hover over one of the parent li elements, the child ul element (the dropdown menu) abruptly pops into existence. When I hover off of it, it goes away as it should (fading out).

Here's a sample of the HTML structure:

```
<header id="masthead">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu-tabletdesktop" class="menu">
        <li><a href="/some-link/">Parent</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="/some-link/a/">Link A</a></li>
                <li><a href="/some-link/b/">Link B</a></li>
                <li><a href="/some-link/c/">Link C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Here's the SCSS:

```
@mixin transition($target, $time) {
    -webkit-transition: $target $time ease-in-out;
    transition: $target $time ease-in-out;
}
header#masthead .main-menu ul > li:not(.wdac-active) > ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
header#masthead .main-menu ul > li > ul.sub-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    @include transition(opacity, 0.6s);
}

header#masthead .main-menu ul > li:hover > ul.sub-menu,
header#masthead .main-menu ul > li:focus > ul.sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    @include transition(opacity, 0.6s);
    display: block;
}

header#masthead .main-menu ul > li.wdac-active > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

The jQuery that adds a .wdac-active class to it after 0.6s is the following:

```
$("#masthead ul.menu > li").on("hover", function() {
    var $menuItem = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $menuItem.toggleClass("wdac-active");
    }, 600);
});
```

So what I want to happen is, on hover, the ul is set to block and slowly fades in, then the wdac-active class is applied. After mousing off of the li, the ul slowly fades out and once the wdac-active class is removed, it's set to be display: none.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? The fade-in is abrupt (not good) but the fade-out is working fine.

Comment: Opacity transition doesn't work while changing display at the same time. You will need to create keyframes for each transition.

Comment: if you're already using jQuery you could use the "fadeIn() method over the child element and then add the class. That way, the fadeIn will change the display and animate it and then the addClass will set it forever

Comment: LordNero, I tried that first but the site had other css that made the fadeIn() or toggleFade() really strange, so I opted not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you position your dropdowns in absolute from the parent, you can use visibility instead of display :

```
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s ease-out;

&.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. I set the submenus to always be blocks and everywhere in my code that was "display" I made the "visibility" property. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For transition to work properly here, you need to work with two css properties - opacity and visibility(instead of display). You can assign your dropdown menu(ul) with absolute position and then use opacity and visibility properties. Then you can transition on both of your css properties.

```
transition: opacity 0.6s ease, visibility 0.6 ease;
```

or

```
transition: opacity 0.6s ease, visibility 0.6 ease;
```